# Check a hash for empty keys, Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash that looks like this

```
$VAR1 = {
      '' => 0,
      'example' => 17953878,
      'test' => 14504908,
      'arbitrary' => 14977444
};
```

I am printing the hash with the basic

```
for (keys %hash) {
    print "$_ : $hash{$_}";
}
```

What is the best way to check for the empty key and remove it before printing the hash?
Also id like to know how I can check if the key is 'undef' or just an empty string, does it evaluate to false? etc.

Comment: What does "empty key" mean for you?

Comment: @kratenko Well thats the thing im not sure how to check what the apperent empty key is? I should have specified the hash structure above was pritned with Data::Dumper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (keys %hash) {
    length  or next;     # key is empty string, skip it
    # $_ eq "" and next; # explicit comparison to ""

    print "$_ : $hash{$_}";
}
```

Checking with `exists`, outside of loop:

```
print "hash has empty string key\n" if exists($hash{""});
```

Comment: keys are always strings (not scalars!), therefore they can't be `undef`.

Comment: @amon indeed, tnx for comment `perl -we 'my %h = (undef => 3, "" => 4); use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%h'`

Answer (score 3):

If your data is coming from an external source, and you know that empty strings are never valid input, you can just do

```
delete $hash{''};
```

before printing.

Comment: This would be my solution :)